# Abort a commit in Git if user.name and user.email are not configured

Tags: git

I use Git intensively with different usernames at different machines. Sometimes, when I clone a repository, I forget to configure `user.name` and `user.email`, and when I commit the very first commit to the local repository without the identity name specified, I get

```
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Yes, it's totally clear what and why Git says like that. (If I notice it, though.) However, is it possible to suppress such behavior and make Git not to propagate my username and hostname as a commit author username? Why I'm asking the question is that I have neither `[user] name =` nor `[user] email =` in my `~/.gitconfig` by intention: I just use different usernames and emails for different groups of repositories and I would like Git just to abort the commit if it cannot get the username and email from the configuration. The worst thing is that I have a custom Git-informative `PS1` configured displaying the current repository username and email right, because I had history rewrites and forced pushes several times before not even noticing that huge Git warnings for username defaults.

Is it possible to abort a commit in Git if `user.name` and `user.email` were not specified by me globally? (I guess it can be fixed by hooks, but hooks are local only, right?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `user.useConfigOnly`:

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

From `git-config(1)`:

> Instruct Git to avoid trying to guess defaults for `user.email` and `user.name`, and instead retrieve the
>              values only from the configuration. For example, if you have multiple email addresses and would like to
>              use a different one for each repository, then with this configuration option set to true in the global
>              config along with a name, Git will prompt you to set up an email before making new commits in a newly
>              cloned repository. Defaults to false.

Comment: As simple as I wanted it to be. I feel ashamed that I couldn't see this option earlier as well as I cannot read my `PS1` nicely sometimes... Thank you!

Comment: Interesting detail: `user.useConfigOnly` seems not to work if `user =` and `email =` in `.gitconfig` have no values (I mean `=\n`) and are not commented out.

Answer (score -1):

If you want git clone to automatically initialize user.email and user.name based on the remote url: https://github.com/DrVanScott/git-clone-init